# Missing Order from Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I received a transaction note from Authorize.net

transaction number 100000056

I don't see it at all on Magento

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Admin -> Reports -> Shopping Cart -> Abandoned Carts` to see if it's there.